# Calculate the byte size of a cJSON object

Tags: c++, c, arduino, esp32, cjson

Right now I'm struggling with calculating the size of a `cJSON` object. So far, I have done this:

```cpp
cJSON *payload = cJSON_CreateObject();
...
size_t size_payload = sizeof(payload);
```

Obviously I initialize the payload object and I print into the terminal to verify the integrity of the data and it is ok. However, after printing the `sizeof` result, it is always 4 as the number of bytes, but for a long string (as mine) it should be around 500 bytes.

Am I missing something here handling `cJSON` object?

Hope you can help, or maybe give me an example of how to get the proper value of the entire size.

Comment: `strlen(cJSON_Print(payload))`?

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof()` is a compile-time constant.  It has no concept of data at runtime.

`sizeof(payload)` is the byte size of your `payload` variable, which is declared as a `cJSON*` pointer.  So its byte size is always the same - `sizeof(void*)`, which is 4 bytes in your case (because you are compiling your app for 32bit).  Its size is not that of the `cJSON` object that it is pointing at.

And even then, if you tried to dereference the pointer and use `sizeof()` on the `cJSON` object itself, ie `sizeof(*payload)`, it would be the byte size of the `cJSON` struct itself at **compile-time**, not the byte size of any data that the `cJSON` object has allocated internally for itself at **runtime**.

AFAICS, `cJSON` does not provide a method for returning the byte size of the JSON data it is holding, so you will just have to format the JSON to a string variable, and then query that string for its size at runtime, eg:

```c
char *str = cJSON_Print(payload); // or cJSON_PrintUnformatted() or cJSON_PrintBuffered() ...
if (str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    cJSON_free(str);
    ...
}
```